# SQL query as an user input using textarea

Tags: php, mysql, sql, textarea, user-input

I'd like to give a user the option of making SQL queries. I placed a textarea into the used form.
When I entered this query `SELECT name FROM user ORDER BY name ASC` , it returned expected result.
But when I tried to used WHERE clause `SELECT name FROM user WHERE SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) = 'J' ORDER BY name ASC` or `SELECT name FROM user WHERE id>1000 ORDER BY name ASC`, neither of the SELECTs worked and I received the following error:

> Not Acceptable
>   An appropriate representation of the requested resource /test/index.php could not be found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What might be the cause of this problem? The first thing that came on my mind was the characters like > will make the URL invalid, but it's not the case.

Comment: How are you transmitting the information from the web page to your application?  POST or GET?  Please post the HTML for the SUBMIT button (if you're submitting a form).

Comment: And also, if your business has ever collected any data on me, may I respectfully ask you to delete it immediately from your database?

Comment: Aside from the obvious dangers of allowing users to enter freeform SQL, how are you posting this to the server? You may need to use `stripslashes` before attempting to execute the SQL.

Comment: Consider what might happen if I were to submit "drop table user" or "update user set name=concat(name, ' is pedobear approved')"

Comment: @horatio nothing would happen since the user is allowed to execute SELECT queries only

Comment: According to your comment, you merely pass through the GET variable: mysql_query(stripslashes($_GET['sql'])). php manual: "For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error. " So you are relying on mysql security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some overcautious software like Suhosin or mod_security or the like, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is probably configured with mod_security, and it is scanning POST data, triggering this response.

See: http://www.howtoforge.com/apache_mod_security_p2

http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/03-configuration.html#N10176

Comment: The for uses GET method. 
"Please post the HTML for the SUBMIT button" <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
"And also, if your business has ever collected any data on me, may I respectfully ask you to delete it immediately from your database?" It's a joke :) If not, I can assure you there is no data about you
mysql_query(stripslashes($_GET['sql'])) is what the command looks like

Comment: @user965748, it's a joke.  Or rather, a warning about allowing direct submission of SQL code to a database with any important, meaningful, or personally identifying data in it — you need to assume that anyone on the internet will be able to do whatever they want to your database.

Comment: @Larry Lustig no problem, the page is in a non-public area, so only selected people have access there.

Comment: you should reply to comments in the threads they occur in (above)

Comment: @horatio OK, I'll. It seems the true reason why it doesn't work has to do something with the characters, because even NATURAL JOIN was allowed.

Comment: I contacted my hosting provider and yes, it was caused by the security mode. Shrapnel and Horatio, thank you for your suggestions.